# Converting timestamp String in a unique Primary Key

Tags: java, sql, database, string, primary-key

I'd like to transform a String (from an XML file) to a DB Primary Key using Java 7.

In particular, I would like to make sure that this values are **unique**, **positive** and **respect the DB primary key specification** that is: NUMBER(20).

The string that i try to transform have this characterization:

> PDR_20140909150001

Obviously i can ignore first part of the string (because are the same for all the file), but i have to transform a timestamp string like `20140909150001` in an *int* value that must be unique and have maximum 20 digit of lenght.

Any idea? How can i do?

Comment: It is compulsory for you to make it int of 20 digits?

Comment: no, it's just an upper bound

Comment: Then you can convert this string in Date object and takes time in second, will give you int value. I think your string is in "PDR_yyyymmddhhmmss" format

Comment: Timestamp is not unique because our system interfaces with various sub-systems. So, we can have scenario in which our system receive same timestamp from different sub-systmes.

Comment: You can simply append 1,2,3 depend on from where you can receive the time stamp and convert it to Double value. i.e if system 1 return "PDR_20140909150001" then make it "PDR_201409091500011" now remove first part and convert number to double

Comment: Or you can simply append current system seconds and convert it to double

Comment: If it is not unique, it is not a good candidate for a PK. A PK should have no semantic meaning apart from being err unique. I'd create a PK (from a sequence or a GUID) and store the timestamp as its own column

Answer (score 1):

you can convert String to int using Integer.parseInt(), I assume that 20140909150001 are unique enough. Hope this help :)

Comment: Unfortunately timestamp is not unique because our system interfaces with various sub-systems. So, we can have scenario in which our system receive same timestamp from different sub-systmes.

Comment: how about these: getDateTime() in java (example, I got: 20140923172200), convert it to String, then append it to 20140909150001. final data is 2014090915000120140923172200. then you can convert it

Comment: i'm following your suggestion, but how can i convert a string of 24 digit (2014090915000120140923172200) in a int value of maximum 20 preserving the uniqueness?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply append current system seconds and convert it to double.

i.e. "PDR_20140909150001" will be converted to "2014090915000159" as String where appended "59" is your current system second as convert this value to Double.

Answer (score 1):

You might use [java.math.BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and map to your database type number(XX).

About uniqueness you might:

- append extra-seconds which are to be thought as one of your sub-system id
- append an auto generated unique id for each db insert

Comment: How can i convert a string of 25 digit like 2014090915000120140923172200x (with 'x' is the auto-generated id) in a int value of maximum 20 preserving the uniqueness?

Comment: @Zany I have suggest `BigInteger` because the upper bound is limited by system memory so it is suitable for big `number(XX)`. I disagree with @bayuforest's solution because I prefer appending a small auto generated unique id instead of a 14 dateTime digits; doing so I will not have the "25-->20" problem. By the way I would do as @Gyro Gearless.